# Using TimeCapsule through PFSense firewall

Tags: network, wifi, airport, time-capsule, router

I'm running some time capsule automatic backups and I've recently totally changed my home network with a PFsense firewall and of course my mac stopped recognizing my time capsule.

- My mac is connected by WIFI to the PFSense router on the interface WLAN with the IP : 192.168.4.12, using DHCP.
- My Time Capsule is connected by Ethernet to the PFSense router on the interface LAN with the IP : 192.168.3.14, using another DHCP server.

There is a firewall rule allowing any request from the WLAN network to the address 192.168.3.14 on the LAN network. And the LAN network can access the WLAN Network with another rule.

This is working fine, I can ping my Time Capsule from my mac, and when I connect by the finder to 192.168.3.14 with CMD+K it mounts without a problem. However, when I open Airport Utility, it doesn't see my time capsule on the network. (Maybe it's only looking for devices on the same subnet ?) but I can connect to it and configure it by specifying it's ip address with CMD+MAJ+O (Use another device).

But while the airport utility is not detecting my time capsule by it's own,the time machine configuration doesn't see the time capsule neither and I can't run any backups.

I would really appreciate if you had any clue to give me on how to make my mac see my time capsule and start making backups again. Thanks in advance,
tourdetour.

Comment: When I connect to my timeCapsule with the wired network and I got a IP like 192.168.3.10, it works. So I really think there are some subnets problems. Maybe I could use a NAT ?

Comment: It seems like bonjour doesn't work on multi subnets. Does anybody know how to forward this service from my LAN to my WLAN on my router in order to be able to detect my devices from my mac ? Or could we use the time capsule / airplay without bonjour ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, that was quite tricky. Like I've said in a comment, Bonjour is used by my Time Capsule to be recognized by the mac but isn't supposed to work on a different subnet. 
I set up an Avahi server on my pfsense router that is forwarding any Bonjour request to the WLAN and I can now access my Timecapsule by wifi, use AirPrint and Airplay. 
For more informations : http://www.avahi.org